# MongoDB: compound index decision

Tags: php, mongodb

I recently had to optimize certain sets of queries on our MongoDB, and run into this particular problem:

say I have a query that match on `A` and `B`, then do a range select on `C`, and output by sorting on `D`, so in shell they look like:

```
db.collection.find({ A: 'something', B: 'something-else', C: { $gt: 100 } })
             .sort({ D: -1 }).limit(10)
```

I [read a post](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/) last year that talked about creating index for such scenario, their basic rules:

1. Exact value match field go first
2. Sorting field comes second
3. Range search ($in, $gt etc.) field comes last

Their tree explanation looks reasonable so I went ahead and created an index as such:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ A:1, B:1, D:-1, C:-1 })
```

Now the problem comes: **mongodb decides BasicCursor is better than this index**. If I `hint` the full index it works (and much faster), but doing that would require quite a few changes on our codebase, so we are trying to avoid that if at all possible.

---

My questions are:

1. Why does mongodb query optimizer decides `{ A:1, E:-1 }`, `{ D:-1 }` or even BasicCursor are better than `{ A:1, B:1, D:-1, C:-1 }`, when my query includes all 4 fields.
2. Is `{ A:1, D:-1 }` redundant, [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) does say using partial index is less efficient?

Furthermore, we also have queries like following:

```
db.collection.find({ A: { $in : ['str1','str2'] }, B: 'something', C: { $gt: 100 } })
             .sort({ D: -1 }).limit(10)
```

To efficiently query it, do we need an extra index like following? Frankly I am not sure how will MongoDB query optimizer treat them.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ B:1, D:-1, C:-1, A:1 })
```

---

These are the explain for my query with and without hint.

- with hint (full index): http://pastebin.com/xtpJ3dsf
- with hint (A,D index): http://pastebin.com/v66QmtsP
- without hint: http://pastebin.com/QAtM0WN0
- without hint (dropped other index): http://pastebin.com/6ZDweiNX

Turns out it was defaulting to `{ A:1, E:-1 }` not `{ A:1, D:-1 }`, which seem even stranger as we did't query on field E.

I dropped the index on `{ A:1, E:-1 }`, now explain tells me it defaults to `{ D:-1 }`, so I dropped it as well, now MongoDB begin using `BasicCursor`... It doesn't seem to like neither my full index nor the `A:1, D:-1` index (despite hint result in much better performance).

This feels weird.

Comment: Most likely the two field compound index produces more results in a shorter period of time as such it the won the race and continues to over the 4 field compound index, this is one of those rare cases in the optimiser. As to whether the two field index is redundant...hmmm, I am gonna go with yes but I would have to see the explain of the two to know for sure

Comment: @Sammaye I have updated my post with explain info.

Comment: I believe this might be the optimiser ditching that index because a,b,c are not in succession, they are interloped with d which breaks exact matching of the index and leaves it up to finding the next quickest index

Comment: @Sammeye you might very well be correct, after dropping just about all index besides my main index, it seems mongodb decides the best approach is BasicCursor. Though it leaves the question, would A,B,C or A,B,C,D be the next best choice?

Comment: The problem is that a,b,c,d would cause scanandorder, hmmm I am surprised that the optimiser doesn't see this, what version of MongoDB is this?

Comment: The problem is that the linked blog post was written more than 18 months ago and in particular they are not considering a large number of optimizations that were made in 2.2 and 2.4 for index usage.  I would recommend reading this article http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/, and specifically, check how B:1, A:1, C:1, D:1 works for you with and without the hint...

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That doesn't really provide a solution it still says that a,b,d,c would be best and that you have to hint to get it to work

Comment: OP - could you run the same query but without a hint and with explain(true) appended to it and put the output in pastebin?   Also can you provide a sample document - I can see that one of those four fields is an array but not which one it is - the rules for array indexes (multiKey) indexes are different, and there are some additional limitations. I'm going to guess "A" (aka categories) is the array?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky thx, i was about to do that today after reading there is a verbose setting for explain. also you are right, A is an array (I edited it out as question was getting quite long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason something "unusual" like this would happen is if your data distribution happens to be such that BasicCursor actually completes the query (i.e. finds all the matching documents) faster than an indexed query.  Same thing for a "partial" index.

A specific case where this would happen, using your data structure as an example is if a has relatively few distinct values at the beginning of a collection, and b has extremely low cardinality (i.e. very few distinct values, like one or a handful) then scanning the collection in order or using a "less efficient" index will show equal or better performance than using theoretically "ideal" index.

Here's an example where the first 1000 documents have a=1 and b=2 - later documents are very differently distributed.

```
> db.compound4.find({a:1, b:2, d:{$lt:100}}).sort({c:-1}).limit(10).explain(true)
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 10,
    "nscannedObjects" : 18,
    "nscanned" : 18,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 46,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 56,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "a" : [
            [
                1,
                1
            ]
        ]
    },
    "allPlans" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1",
            "n" : 18,
            "nscannedObjects" : 18,
            "nscanned" : 18,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "a" : [
                    [
                        1,
                        1
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1_b_1_c_1_d_1 reverse",
            "n" : 10,
            "nscannedObjects" : 10,
            "nscanned" : 20,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "a" : [
                    [
                        1,
                        1
                    ]
                ],
                "b" : [
                    [
                        2,
                        2
                    ]
                ],
                "c" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "d" : [
                    [
                        100,
                        -1.7976931348623157e+308
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
            "n" : 18,
            "nscannedObjects" : 18,
            "nscanned" : 18,
            "indexBounds" : {

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Since the compound index is large it takes longer to traverse than the smaller partial index and because of selectivity of "b" is not very good (i.e. very bad) it makes that query plan fall behind.

Comment: i will accept this as an answer since it points me to the right direction. see my own answer for exact reason on why the full index wasn't choosing.

Comment: my point was that specific data distribution will govern the best index _at this time_ - the optimizer will periodically retest though, so if data distribution changes, it will "notice" and change the query plan (barring limitations and bugs :) )

Answer (score 0):

After running my original query with `explain(true)` the reasoning behind mongodb query optimizer is much clearer.

It's because field `C`, which was a range search on an `int` field and was expected to have high selectivity does not have many matching results at the start of search (especially when results are ordered by `D` and descending, which was a date field.)

The [base logic](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) behind mongodb query optimizer appear to be: **given the same number of `n` result, use the plan (index) with smallest `nscanned` (best if nscanned = n)**. In case of a small n, eg. `limit(10)`, optimizer may not use the most efficient index we planned for it.

In my case, it turns out the both index `{ D:-1 }` and `BasicCursor` beats the full index on such test. So the mystery is solved.

PS: for curiosity, these are the `explain(true)` output for my testing dataset:

- no `C` field matching our range search: http://pastebin.com/5ibFDs44
- every `C` field matching our range search: http://pastebin.com/4Y35dMXM

Hope this helps someone :)